# Parameter mismatch for seeding the users table on Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

I'm trying to seed the users table on Laravel 5.2. I've a custom column called `role`. I'm using Faker to seed the users table. However, I need to populate the `role` column either with Administrator or Customer. So, I've passed an array and that returned Parameter mismatch error.

Here's the relevant code I'm trying with:

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->email,
        'password' => 123456,
        'role' => ['Administrator', 'Customer'],
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ];
})
```

I know that it only accept string instead of an array. So, how do you do that when you want to seed the database with multiple particular data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Faker` to get a random element:

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'name' => $faker->name,
        'email' => $faker->email,
        'password' => 123456,
        'role' => $faker->randomElement(['Administrator', 'Customer']),
//                 ^^^^^^^ here ^^^^^^^
        'remember_token' => str_random(10),
    ];
})
```

Comment: Thanks, dude. Didn't know there's a `Faker` method for random element :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using random index generation (in your case 0 or 1) and retrieving value from the array of possible values (['Administrator', 'Customer']) by this index.

```
$i = rand(0, 1);
$roleOptions = ['Administrator', 'Customer'];
$role = $roleOptions[$i];
```

Also if you would like to have much more users than administrators, you can look for something like this: [changing probability of getting a random number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8529665/changing-probability-of-getting-a-random-number)